# TypeScript - Adding methods to a class using decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript

First of all, I'm quite new to TypeScript so apologies if this is a stupid question.

I'm trying to create a base class that can be extended with additional functionality. I tried to use inheritance but then I realised you can't extend multiple classes. My next attempt was to use decorators, which seems to work fine but TypeScript doesn't give me code completion for methods from decorators.

```
function Talks<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        sayHello(): void {
            console.log('Hello');
        }
    }
}

function Walks<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        move(): void {
            console.log('Walk');
        }
    }
}

function Chargeable<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        chargeBattery(): void {
            console.log('Charging');
        }
    }
}

@Talks
@Walks
@Chargeable
class Robot { }

@Chargeable
class Calculator { }

const robot = new Robot();

robot.sayHello();
robot.move();
robot.chargeBattery();

const calculator = new Calculator();

calculator.chargeBattery();
```

[Open in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20Talks%3CT%20extends%20%7Bnew(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%3A%7B%7D%7D%3E(constructor%3AT)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20constructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sayHello()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Hello')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Walks%3CT%20extends%20%7Bnew(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%3A%7B%7D%7D%3E(constructor%3AT)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20constructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20move()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Walk')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Chargeable%3CT%20extends%20%7Bnew(...args%3Aany%5B%5D)%3A%7B%7D%7D%3E(constructor%3AT)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20constructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20chargeBattery()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Charging')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40Talks%0D%0A%40Walks%0D%0A%40Chargeable%0D%0Aclass%20Robot%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40Chargeable%0D%0Aclass%20Calculator%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20robot%20%3D%20new%20Robot()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Arobot.sayHello()%3B%0D%0Arobot.move()%3B%0D%0Arobot.chargeBattery()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20calculator%20%3D%20new%20Calculator()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Acalculator.chargeBattery()%3B%0D%0A).

1) Is there a way to add code autocomplete for methods added with decorators?

2) Is there generally a better way to extend classes with additional functionality (mix and match)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design decorators can't change the type of the symbol they are decorating.

You can use the decorators as regular functions and pass in the class manually. Your types are already correct for this task and this is actually the [recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743) way to do mix-ins in Typescript:

```
const Robot = Chargeable(Walks(Talks(class {

})));

const Calculator = Chargeable(class { });

const robot = new Robot();

robot.sayHello();
robot.move();
robot.chargeBattery();

const calculator = new Calculator();

calculator.chargeBattery();
```

Comment: The TS docs state that it's not able to infer the type of the decorated methods https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators. Will this change in the future?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I don't expect any work on decorators as they are not on a path to ES standardization and TS tries to follow ES standardization these days